# C structs using self

Tags: c, struct, reference, c-preprocessor, self

I have some code that a program generated for me, and I really do not understand *why* it does what it does. The language is plain C, and a struct is generated.

.h-file:

```
struct X_IMPL {
   sint32 y;
};

struct X {
   struct X_IMPL * IMPL;
};
```

.c-file:

```
#define _my_y self->IMPL->y

sint32 do_something(struct X * self)
{
    return _my_y*13;
}
```

I do assume that `_my_y` now points to a variable inside the struct, and can be used to change the struct's variable. My question is, why would code be generated this way? Is there any advantage compared to just simply using the parameter's reference? When a reference is created with a define like that, do I really need that parameter at all?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The `#define` doesn't "create" anything, it's just a textual replacement macro. Where the source has `_my_y`, the compiler will see `self->IMPL->y`. Not sure what you mean by "reference" in this context either.

Comment: All it's doing is reducing the verbosity of the code (imagine if you had lots of code in `do_something`, having `self->IMPL->y` everywhere could get repetitive.  That said, hiding stuff like this behind macros is generally considered bad-practice (at least, for code written by humans!).

Comment: @unwind: With reference I just meant that `my_y` and `self->IMPL->y` would point to the same place in memory.

Comment: @Pphoenix I think you're not really understanding what happens in this code. `_my_y` doesn't exist as a symbol in the compiled program; it's the name of a `#define` so it will be replaced by the preprocessor and never seen by the compiler. Try to read the preprocessor output (`-E` with gcc).

Comment: @unwind: Ah! Yes, thank you! My C is kind of rusty ;)

Comment: @unwind: If I get this right, `_my_y` would be replaced with `self->IMPL->y`, and thus I need the parameter to define self, am I right? As the code is written now it felt like the self parameter was excessive, but removing it the compiler would not know where to look?

Comment: The macro requires the variable `self` to be available where it's used, yes. In code like this (object-oriented functions in C) you must always pass around a `self` (or `this`) pointer that points at the object that the method should operate upon.

Comment: It would make more sense if `struct X_IMPL` has only forward declaration in header file and actual definition in `.c` file.

Comment: A general note about using `#define` like this: it may seem like a good idea when you write the code initially, but it's a road to incomprehensible code with bugs that are hard to track, and subtle mistakes which compiler does not warn you about. It's not enough to know C to understand that code, one must also for example know the special meaning of function parameter named `self` (which is used by these macros in a special way). In effect `self` becomes an extra language keyword, with special meaning, even though compiler does not know it.

Comment: @hyde: Yes, I hope that this can be changed in the code generator or I will have have a lot of code to debug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of preferences, as you can do that in many ways, this one is not that sheer. On the first line, where the define is, it assigns nothing but define a macro for accessing a struct pointer through a struct pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are seeing is "object oriented programming" in C. Note that it's not usually 1:1 equivalent to OOP in C++/Java/C#/whatever, because the OOP mechanisms are not built-in, but implemented explicitly. So different projects and different developers might write quite different code for same thing, while in some other language with built-in OOP features, they'd all just use the built-in features the same way.

The `do_something` in C++ might look like this:

```
// do_something is public member function AKA method of class X
sint32 X::do_something()
{
    // y is this->y, private member variable of class X
    return y * 13; 
}
```

Comment: If that's the reason, then it's a poor tool. Real OOP in C would either use function pointers in some way or (more likely) implement member functions as plain functions taking a struct pointer as parameter, where the struct pointer is of incomplete type and its contents are unknown to the caller. Then the internals of the function are irrelevant and the `#define` would just be obfuscation. I would rather suspect the `#define` is there for a simplification to suit some kind of given API.

Comment: @Lundin There's so little code shown, and it may not be 100% identical to the real code, that I wouldn't pass the judgement of "OOP purity". `do_something` very much looks like a "member function of class X" written in C, the `self` parameter with the implicit meaning is kinda giveaway. And yeah, having that kind of `#define` in generated code is a bit of WTF I agree (unless there's some external reason for it).

Comment: Yes, this was not the full project (which is huge). X is also another name but it was so long that it would just be confusing to read it all, therefore I replaced it with something more readable :)